# invoke block from another function

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, block

I need some help with blocks

I want to do something like this:

```
- (void)function {
      self.block =  ^(NSArray * array){
        NSLog(@"BLOCK %@", array);
    };
}


- (void)anotherFunction {
   block(array)
}
```

Is it possible?!)

Comment: Why not? Legal code...

Comment: in doesn't work though)

Comment: +k06a, can you provide example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is fine... You could do the following

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^block)(NSArray *array);

...

- (void)function {
    self.block =  ^(NSArray * array){
        NSLog(@"BLOCK %@", array);
    };
}


- (void)anotherFunction {
    if (self.block)
        self.block(array);
}
```

Comment: should I do something like alloc init for this block? I'm not getting callbacks and if i remove "if (self.block)" program crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: you're probably calling `anotherFunction` before you called `function`. You need to set the block before you can invoke it

Comment: THANK YOU! that was so stupid mistake from my side))

Comment: It's fine to call messages on objects that are `nil` (e.g. `[nilObject someMethod]`) but you can't call a block that points to `nil` (e.g. `nilBlock()`), which is why you need to add the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible

**first:-**

do type def in your .h file the block type you intend to use it helps.

```
typedef void (^blockForYou)(NSArray*);//typedef helps in recognizing and better    understanding blocks and easy to use as well
```

now make a property of the block type make it copy.

```
@property(nonatomic,copy)blockForYou yourBlock;
```

Now in .m file copy block to your property.

```
self.yourBlock=^(NSArray* arrayData){
        //get your array here
    };
```

now from other function call your block simply..

```
self.yourBlock(<pass your array here>);
```

hope it helps .

Comment: You shouldn't assign blocks in properties, they should be copied instead